# Getting the src from text using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am adding images to a WP site via a shortcode:

`[figure src="" url"" caption=""]`

Where the `src` is the image source, the `url` is the link to a larger image (if wanted), and the `caption` is the caption.

I am trying to get the `src` from the above basing it off this code:

```
$pattern = '/<img[^>]*src=\"?(?<src>[^\"]*)\"?[^>]*>/im';
preg_match( $pattern, $html, $matches ); 
if($matches['src']) {
    return $matches['src'];
}
```

But am trying to figure out how to get the `[figure]` match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\[figure(( src="(?<src>[^"]+)")?|( url="(?<url>[^"]+)")?|( caption="(?<caption>[^"]+)")?)*\]/i
```

> [figure url="http://example.com/large.gif" caption="my caption" src="http://example.com/figure.gif"]

```
Array
(
    [0] => [figure url="http://example.com/large.gif" caption="my caption" src="http://example.com/figure.gif"]
    [1] => 
    [2] =>  src="http://example.com/figure.gif"
    [src] => http://example.com/figure.gif
    [3] => http://example.com/figure.gif
    [4] =>  url="http://example.com/large.gif"
    [url] => http://example.com/large.gif
    [5] => http://example.com/large.gif
    [6] =>  caption="my caption"
    [caption] =>  my caption
    [7] => my caption
)
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, can I ask is there any way to strip back the pattern to just get the src? I like all the other options, but I'm only in for the src.

Comment: My regexp is built to match the attributes in random order. If you only need src, you can match using `/\[figure.* src="(?<src>[^"]+)".*\]/iU` instead

Comment: Thanks for both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$foo = [figure src="" url"" caption=""];
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $foo, $array ) ;
$finalStr = $array[0];
$explode = explode("=", $finalStr);
echo $explode[1];
```

Comment: Oops I gave $array[1]. I updated my answer with $array[0] can you try now?

Comment: Your answer is currently giving me the `src=IMG.jpg` where I only need the `IMG.jpg`

Comment: Also anyway to make it `$matches['src'];` rather than `$matches[0];` unless they're the same?